# Jenkins empty cucumber html reports post build

Tags: html, jenkins

I am very new to jenkins and I am facing a really strange issue. I have been searching for an answer to this problem for a long time without finding any results.

I am using the Html published plugin on Jenkins 2.30 with this information:

```
HTML directory to archive:  \target\reports\html\
Index page[s]:  index.html
```

As you can see, that is where my report is generated by Jenkins :

```
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level C:\Jenkins\CDK\workspace\ACEWS Daily Test Auto build\target\reports\html to /home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/ACEWS Daily Test Auto build/htmlreports/HTML_Report
```

However when I click on the Html report button on Jenkins, it's displaying an empty page.

I decided to connect to the remote machine I use as a slave to check the repository and the url *C:\Jenkins\CDK\workspace\ACEWS Daily Test Auto build\target\reports\html\index.html* is working fine and displaying my report correctly.

However, I have a popup telling me that Internet Explorer has restricted the page from running scripts or ActiveX controls and I have to "Allow blocked content".

Might this conflict be the reason of the conflict with Jenkins report display ?

Many thanks,

Rama